# Which GC to use when profiling memory?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling, visualvm

I use the NetBeans profiler (which is actually an embedded VisualVM) to monitor the memory consumption of my Java applications. I use the *heap* view, the *surviving generation* view, and *memory dumps* to track memory leaks.

The heap view shows the total of used memory, but it's a bit chaotic, due to the way the garbage collector manages the memory. The graph is essentially sawtooth-shaped, and thus not particularly readable. Sometimes, I force the GC to happen, so that I can have a more precise value of the real memory consumption.

I was wondering : is there a garbage collector which is more appropriate for memory profiling, and which would yield a heap graph closer to the real memory usage ? Or more generally, what JVM settings (`-XX` options or other) can I use in order to efficiently track memory leaks ?

[image: example heap graph]

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing in your graph *is* the real behavior of your applications memory utilization.  The repeated sawtooth pattern is likely due to allocations of short lived objects which are being scavenged.  If you believe you have a memory leak, take a heap dump snapshot and see what objects are being retained in the heap.  You can take a snapshot using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) and open the resulting dumpfile using [HPjmeter](http://www.hpjmeter.com).

Comment: +1: Whether it's "readable" or not, the sawtooth pattern is what *actually* happens to the amount of memory used.

Comment: You are right : I shouldn't have said "real memory usage", since the graph actually shows that. Instead, I should have said "how can the graph be closer to the memory used by surviving instances, without being polluted by short-lived instances".

Comment: To capture that detail, you really need a heap dump.  Think about it, even if the graph was smooth -- you wouldn't know what objects are actually sticking around by looking at this kind of graph.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the GC you intend to use without the profiler. Using this approach you will get a graph which is more like how the application will behave, though not always as readable.

If you want a graph which is more readable, but not as realistic, you can increase the minimum memory size to say 1 GB.  This will result in less GCs and a less spikey graph but may not help you except make the graph prettier.

Comment: I'm more interrested in seeing what actions in the user interface make the app allocate memory without releasing it.

Comment: I am not sure how looking at the graph will help you. Any memory leak in the GUI is likely to be slow so you will have to repeat an action many times or keep track of the number of objects you expect to see and how many object are retained after a full GC.  This will be especially hard to find if there is no leak. ;)